# Will be finishing vs Will have finished

Tags: future-tense

What's the difference of meaning for this phrases:

- By 6 o'clock. **I will be finishing** the lesson.
- By 6 o'clock. **I will have finished** the lesson.

I am making an english exercise and I think that these 2 options are valid to make the phrase correct. Anyway, I don't know whats the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The question really comes down to the context in which we use these two constructions.

Typically, we say things like:

> I will be finishing the lesson around six so I should be able to meet you shortly after that.

The speaker looks ahead to a likely situation in order to make a subsequent arrangement.

On the other hand, the future perfect tense is one that people use to imagine that they are looking back at an event that still lies in the future. It's a way of picturing future events as if they have already taken place. So they say things like:

> By six o'clock I will have completed the exam.
>   By the end of the year my military service will have finished.
>   By this time tomorrow I will have arrived back home.

So while both constructions are common, they tend to be used in different situations.

http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/tenses/future_perfect.htm

Answer (score 0):

**I will be finishing the lesson** means though my lesson will not be completely finished but after a very small time I would finish it.
**I will have finished the lesson** means lesson would be completely finished by 6 o'clock.